# IONIC- No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present

Tags: ionic

Desarrollo una aplicación Ionic, y tengo varias peticiones a archivos PHP, que devuelven datos. esto funciona perfecto. Ahora bien, cuando quiero recuperar con  `$http.get` un archivo json, me da el siguiente error.

```
Failed to load http://www.xxxxxx.com/ea/json/categories.json:
No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested resource.
Origin 'file://' is therefore not allowed access.
```

Les agrego código, y les agradezco la ayuda que me puedan brindar.

```
var armo = 'http://www.xxxxxx.com/ea/json/categories.json';
    $http.get(armo).success(function(response) {
        $scope.categories = response;
    });
```

Answer (score 2):

Buenas, necesitas configurar un proxy de ionic en el archivo ionic.config.json :

```
  "proxies": [
    {
      "path": "/json",
      "proxyUrl": "http://xxxx.com/json/"
    }
  ]
```

y un ejemnplo consumiendo el api

```
  getAllPosts() {
    return new Promise(resolve => {
      this.http.get('/json/posts')
        .map(res => res.json())
        .subscribe(data => {
          this.data = data;
          resolve(this.data);
        });
    });
  }
```

prueba y cuentanos.

Comment: Gracias ! Funciona perfecto !

Answer (score 0):

> No 'Access-Control-Allow-Origin' header is present on the requested
>   resource.

Este mensaje significa que tu aplicación de PHP no ha sido configurada para aceptar solicitudes de aplicaciones externas, si deseas debuguear puedes utilizar un **plugin en chrome** para eliminar estos problemas o **POSTMAN** la cual es una aplicación para testear APIs y así verificar tus URLs donde solicitas o envias recursos pero te recomiendo ampliamente que configures tu aplicación para aceptar solicitudes externas.